# ASP.NET CustomError Handling in MasterPage Error Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, master-pages, custom-errors

I redirect Errors to Error.aspx

```
 <system.web>
        <customErrors defaultRedirect="error.aspx" mode="On">
        <error redirect="error.aspx" statusCode="500" />
 </system.web>
```

and the problem is that there is also second error in ErrorMasterPage of Error.aspx

```
<script Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ErrorMaster.Master" runat="Server">
```

and CustomError can not handle the second error while its like a loop ( it will redirect to error.aspx and Masterpage of Error.aspx has Error.

here is problem:

Example:

Login.aspx(has Error) -> Error.aspx -> ErrorMasterPage.Master (has Error) -> Show Yellow Page
Thanks

Comment: You should fix the error in your error page. What else would you do in that situation?

Comment: I do not see any question or anything wrong in your post ...

Comment: @Frédéric : the error is in Masterpageof Error and is not in Error.aspx

Comment: @Madhur , I added an Example to Post

Comment: @Reza - The error page should be as free of possible errors as you can make it. It should not necessarily rely on a master page, and if it does, that master page should be certified error free before it is viable.

Comment: @Reza : As Frederic said, the only option is to fix the error in master page. You cannot afford to have error in your error page, that's why most of them are based on pure HTML.

Comment: @All thanks seems logical that Error page should not have error and be a simple HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing automatic redirection using web.config I'd say you should have an error page so simple that almost no server error is possible. If you're accessing the database on that page, you would enter on a loop if the error is related with that.

Another option would be redirecting to the error page using the error handler on global.asax. This would involve C# logic. There, you could detect if the error was generated on error.aspx and on that case, you could redirect to fatalerror.aspx (a white page just showing a message for instance).