# Asp.net handle errors on certain pages differently

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Application_Error handler in my Global.asax file.  However, I load many pages using an XHR request and would rather these "sub pages" return javascript or a real 500 code for my main app to process, rather than an error page.

Is it possible to handle errors on certain pages in a different way?  Can a master page handle its own errors in a page extending it without bubbling it up to Global.asax?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest writing your own custom code in application_error subroutine  check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509827/asp-net-customerror-handling-in-masterpage-error-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling the Page_Error event in my page seems to be what I want:

```
  protected void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    Response.Redirect("~/SubError.aspx", true);
  }
```

In my SubError.aspx page I have my app specific javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The Application_Error handler in Global.asax will apply to all **unhandled errors** in your web application (you can and should do specific error handling inside your page methods), but you can put logic around whether or not you call **Server.ClearError** inside your Application_Error handler.

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355:

> If you do not call Server.ClearError
>   or trap the error in the Page_Error or
>   Application_Error event handler, the
>   error is handled based on the settings
>   in the <customErrors> section of the
>   Web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your Global.asax is handling the error is because that is the fall back event handler for any underhanded exceptions in you app.  Make sure to handle your errors (try {} catch {}) where you will be performing the asynchronous request.

I think you should be able to alter the response code as well, so your code returns a 500 response if you do catch an exception.

Typically I like to return an error message and display it as a javascript alert if functionality will be broken by a failed request.

I'm not sure if master pages can handle their encapsulated pages errors?  Any reason why you don't put your asynchronous end points in an .asmx file?

Answer (score 1):

Another point of contention is any HttpModules you have registered can also do error handling.